# How to get only virtual attributes. Node.JS + Mongoose + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider I have a *Mongoose schema* defined

```
var Schema_MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Field1: String, Field2: String
});
```

I have added virtual attribute & setting options in the following way:

```
Schema_MySchema.virtual('USERNAME').get(function () {
    return this.Field1;
});

Schema_MySchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```

Using the schema object to retrieve the data from MongoDB as follows:

```
var Mod_Obj = mongoose.model('SchemaName', Schema_MySchema);
var Model_Instance = new Mod_Obj();
Model_Instance.find({}, function (err, docs) {
   /* 
      Here I get a object docs with following structure:
      [{ _id: ObjectId("511XXXdff9c4c419000008"), 
          Field1: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_1', 
          Field2: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_2',
          USERNAME: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_1'
      }]
  */
});
```

Now I want to remove actual attribute returned from MongoDB, say I want to remove `Field1` from `docs`

I tried following ways to remove:

**1.** `delete docs.Field1;`

**2.** `var Json_Obj = docs.toJSON(); delete Json_Obj.Field1;`

**3.** `var Json_Obj = docs.toObject({ virtuals: true }); delete Json_Obj.Field1;`

**4.** `delete docs[0].Field1;`

**5.** `delete docs[0]['Field1'];`

All the ways didn't work. :-(

If execute for testing on simple JSON it worked:

```
var a = { 'A' : 1, 'B': 2 };
delete a.A;
console.log(a); //prints only object with B attribute only. i.e. { B: 2 }
```

Could anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: did you try `delete docs['Field1']` and what what was output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the index there as `docs` is an array.

if your docs has the following structure

```
[{ _id: ObjectId("511XXXdff9c4c419000008"), 
      Field1: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_1', 
      Field2: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_2',
      USERNAME: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_1'
  }]
```

the deletion code should be

```
delete docs[index]['Field1']
```

ie. to delete `Field1` of 1st element

```
delete docs[0]['Field1']
```

**UPDATED TO COMMENTS:**

please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object) on SO.

Here you will need to do like

```
var k = docs[index].toObject();
delete k['Field1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the doc after field is deleted, Try as follows

```
var Mod_Obj = mongoose.model('SchemaName', Schema_MySchema);
var Model_Instance = new Mod_Obj();
Model_Instance.find({}, function (err, docs) {
   /* 
      Here I get a object docs with following structure:
      [{ _id: ObjectId("511XXXdff9c4c419000008"), 
          Field1: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_1', 
          Field2: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_2',
          USERNAME: 'SOMEvalueFromMongoDB_1'
      }]
  */
delete docs[0].Field1;
docs[0].save(function(err){
if(err){
console.log(err);
}else{
console.log("Field1 is deleted");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found some solution.
Here is the way to do it with Mongoose

```
schema.options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
  // remove the _id of every document before returning the result
  delete ret._id;
}
```

Go to [Document.toObject([options])](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) then scroll to topic **Transform**

Answer (score 0):

You need update model to return it.

```
toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function(doc, ret) {
         ret.id = ret._id;
         delete ret._id;
      }
}
```