# delete property doesn't work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I wonder why I can't delete password object, my console result shows the password is still there, I wonder why.

```
User.comparePassword(password, user.password , (err, result) => {
  if (result === true){
    User.getUserById(user._id, (err, userResult) => {
      delete userResult.password

      const secret = config.secret;
      const token = jwt.encode(userResult, secret);

      console.log(userResult)

      res.json({success: true, msg: {token}});
    });
  } else {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error, Incorrect password!'});
  }
}
```

Comment: What is userResult? Maybe its frozen or sth like that?

Comment: please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239464/javascript-delete-object-property-not-working

Comment: @Jonasw is a user object, no it's not frozen.

Comment: @RaghavGarg tried but doesn't work.

Comment: please try this, `let userObj = Object.assign({}, userResult)` then delete the property `password` of object `userObj`, like: `delete userObj.password`

Comment: if that doesn't work, can you move `console.log(userResult)` right below `delete userResult.password`? just to be sure that `jwt.encode` doesn't mutate `userResult` somehow.

Comment: @RaghavGarg doesn't work. it still have password property

Comment: `User` is sequelize model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. You cannot delete property from Mongoose query, because you get some Mongoose wrapper. In order to manipulate object you need to transform it to JSON object. So there are three possible way that I can remember to do that:

1) Call `toObject` method mongoose object (`userResult`) like this:

```
 let user = userResult.toObject();
 delete user['password'];
```

2) Redefine `toJson` method of `User` model:

```
UserSchema.set('toJSON', {
        transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
            delete ret.password;
            return ret;
        }
});
```

3) Query can return object without specified field, so that you don't need to delete anything:

```
 User.findById(user._id, {password: 0}, function (err, userResult) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much didn't know it has anything to do with mongoose.

Comment: I am glad I could help you :)