# Cant remove field from JSON object - Node JS

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

I have a route that generates a PDF.

```
featureRoutes.route('/report/').get(function (req, res) {
Feature.find(function (err,features){
if(err){
 console.log(err);
}
else {
pdf.create(features.toString()).toStream(function (err, stream) {
  if (err) return res.send(err);
  res.type('pdf');
  stream.pipe(res);
});
}
});
});
```

The contents of the pdf is a JSON object that looks like this.

```
    [ { _id: 5ad5ddddcd054b2b5b20143c,
name: 'Project sidebar',
description: '<p>The project sidebar that we previewed in&nbsp;<a href="https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/jira-6-4-release-notes-678561444.html">JIRA 6.4</a>&nbsp;is here to stay. We built this new navigation experience to make it easier for you to find what you need in your projects. It&#39;s even better, if you are using JIRA Agile: your backlog, sprints, and reports are now just a click away. If you&#39;ve used the sidebar with JIRA Agile before, you&#39;ll notice that cross-project boards, which include multiple projects, now have a project sidebar as well &mdash;&nbsp;albeit a simpler version.</p>\n',
__v: 0 }
```

I need to strip the _id field and the __V field. I try this by:

```
    delete features._id
```

and

```
    delete features.__V
```

But the PDF generated still includes the id and __V field

[image]

How to remove the fields properly in node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript delete object property not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239464/javascript-delete-object-property-not-working)

Comment: is `features` an array or json. from the code it looks like it is a json within array ? could it be `delete features[0]._id`

Comment: @Macintosh_89 - it does not deletes any item, I am using node 8.11

Comment: Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51982694/2034750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restricted the fields with a .select at the end of Feature.find

```
  .select("-__v -_id");
```

Comment: How can you do it while `create`?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/51982694/2034750, it may helps.