# How to delete an Item from JSON Object using nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using node v8.11, not able to delete an item from the object which creates and returns new object from the mongoDB.

Sample response after creating:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "device": "",
    "session":"",
    "_id": "5b7e78c3cc7bca3867bbd1c9",
    "createdAt": "2018-08-23T09:05:07.134Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-08-23T09:05:07.134Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Trying to remove "_id" from the response like below:

```
tokens.create(req.body).then(function(session){
     delete session._id;
     return res.send(session); // _id still exist
});
```

I have seen the delete is deprecated in ES6, is this case issue?
How can I delete an Item, in one line using the key?

Comment: Mongoose returns bson types so you need to convert it to pure javascript object. Then ```delete``` might work!!

Comment: @DevangNaghera exactly what I have mentioned in the answer. That is what OP needs

Comment: @DevangNaghera - Yes, I got it. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a object using mongoose model then it will return you a model object instead of plain javascript object. So, when you do `delete session._id;` it will not work as `session` is a model object and it does not allow to change the property on model object directly.

You need to change the model object to plain JS object using `toJSON()` or `toObject()` method of model object and delete property on that:

```
tokens.create(req.body).then(function(session) {
  var sessionObj = session.toJSON();
  delete sessionObj._id;
  return res.send(sessionObj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `destructuring` and `rest`:

```js
var res = {
    "name": "",
    "device": "",
    "session":"",
    "_id": "5b7e78c3cc7bca3867bbd1c9",
    "createdAt": "2018-08-23T09:05:07.134Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-08-23T09:05:07.134Z",
    "__v": 0
};

var { _id, ...ret } = res ;

console.log(ret);
```