# Object not mutating

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

Trying to mutate objects in a for loop.

I am expecting `console.log(dish)` to log the `dish` object with an `ingredients` property containing an array of unshifted `ingredient`s.

When I log `dish.ingredients`, it logs the ingredients.

When I log `dish`, it logs the `dish` objects without the ingredients.

Why is this?

```
for (let dish of dishArray) {
  dish['ingredients'] = []
  for (let ingredient of ingredientsArray) {
    if (dish._id.equals(ingredient._dishID)) {
      dish['ingredients'].unshift(ingredient)
    }
  }
  console.log(dish['ingredients'])             <------------- 
  console.log(dish)                            <-------------         
}
```

`dishArray` is an array of `dish` objects returned from a mongoose query.

Comment: What's the value of `dishArray`, and what is your expected output? It looks like you're doing console.log on `dish['ingredients']`, but pushing `dish` to `newDishArray`, is this intended?

Comment: @DanielT. any ideas ?

Comment: I asked you two questions, I can't help unless you answer them.

Comment: @DanielT I edited my question with further details.

Answer (score 0):

Without further knowledge of your code, plain javascript `==` will do the job

```js
var dishArray = [{
  _id: '0'
}, {
  _id: '1'
}];
var ingredientsArray = [{
  _id: '0',
  _dishID: '0'
}, {
  _id: '1',
  _dishID: '1'
}];

for (let dish of dishArray) {
  dish['ingredients'] = [];

  for (let ingredient of ingredientsArray) {
    if (dish._id == ingredient._dishID) {
      dish['ingredients'].unshift(ingredient);
    }
  }

  console.log(dish['ingredients']);
  console.log(dish);
}
```

Comment: turns out it's the returned mongoose object that doesn't play friendly with mutations

Comment: Then maybe you could try to lean() or toObject() your Mongoose object, by following the provided answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object