# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an object which is passed ti the n=modal component in the form

```
data =[
  {
    _id: "5ba241b4efa8da2f1464ca81", 
    title: "Zero To One", 
    author: "Peter Thiel", 
    isbn: 1279031943, 
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I want to access the title key on the data but when I do I get a **TypeError.** 
I tried converting it to a string using `JSON.stringigy()` but I still got the same error. 
I am trying to access the data within the modal so when the modal opens, the value of the inputs in the modal is set with the data from the Table so I can easily edit them

When I `console.log(data[0])` I get the items in the object but as soon as I log `console.log(data[0].title)` the **TypeError** appears again.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Update.css';
import Search from '../Search/Search';
// import Modal from './Modal/Modal';

const Table = ({ data, openBookDetails }) => (
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                <th scope="col">No. Of Copies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(row => 
                <TableRow key={row.id} row={row} openBookDetails={openBookDetails}/>
            )}

        </tbody>
    </table>
)

const TableRow = ({ row, openBookDetails }) => (
     <tr class="table-light" onClick={openBookDetails}>
        <th scope="row" >{row.title}</th>
        <td >{row.author}</td>
        <td >{row.isbn}</td>
        <td >24</td>
    </tr>
)

const Modal = ({ closeBookDetails, isBookDetailsOpen, children, data }) => {
    const showHideClassName = isBookDetailsOpen ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';

    console.log(data[0].title);

    return (
      <div className={showHideClassName}>

                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">Update Book</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="Enter title of book" value={data}/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="author">Author</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" aria-describedby="author" placeholder="Enter author name" value={data}/>                        
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="isbn">ISBN</label>
                                <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="isbn" aria-describedby="isbn" placeholder="Enter ISBN number" value={data.title}/>                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="copies">Number of Copies</label>
                                <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="copies" aria-describedby="copies" placeholder="Enter the number of copies" value={data.title}/>                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={closeBookDetails}>Close</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
          {children}
      </div>
    );
  };

class Update extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestions: [],
            setOfAllBooks: [],
            searchedBooks: [],
            isBookDetailsOpen: false,
        };

        this.setTableData = this.setTableData.bind(this);
        this.openBookDetails = this.openBookDetails.bind(this);
        this.closeBookDetails = this.closeBookDetails.bind(this);
    }

    setTableData(searchedBook){
        this.setState({searchedBooks: searchedBook})

        console.log(this.state.searchedBooks)
    }

    openBookDetails(){
        console.log('openBookDetails')
        this.setState({ isBookDetailsOpen: true})
    }

    closeBookDetails(){
        this.setState({ isBookDetailsOpen: false})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>            
                <Search state={this.state} setTableData={this.setTableData} />
                <Table data={this.state.searchedBooks} openBookDetails={this.openBookDetails}/>
                <Modal data={this.state.searchedBooks} isBookDetailsOpen={this.state.isBookDetailsOpen} closeBookDetails={this.closeBookDetails} />
                {/* <Modal /> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Update;
```

Comment: did you try this:`console.log(data[0]['title'])` ?

Comment: Tried that just now. Didn't work

Comment: What is the source of this object? Is seems to be a mongoose document, you should try to use .toObject() on it. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object

Comment: One more thing, you're passing an undefined value to your TableRow key, since the object doesn't contain an id property, only a private _id. But I believe this is not the source of your error.

Comment: toObject() didn;t work.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in data as this.state.searchedBooks you are passing in the defined object, but from your code I can't see where you are actually setting the value to the array listed above.  Are you missing part of the code?

Doing a console log on this would not return an error if done as console.log(data[0]) but would return a type error for data[0].title or anything other part of this object.

Can you try something like this:

```
if(data) {
  console.log(data[0].title)
}
```

So we can tell if the response from the server has arrived.  Then maybe this will help to make a further assessment.

Also have you considered using an arrow function within the Update component so you can eliminate the need to bind these functions.

```
class Update extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: '',
        suggestions: [],
        setOfAllBooks: [],
        searchedBooks: [],
        isBookDetailsOpen: false,
    };
}

setTableData = (searchedBook) => {
    this.setState({searchedBooks: searchedBook})

    console.log(this.state.searchedBooks)
}

openBookDetails = () => {
    console.log('openBookDetails')
    this.setState({ isBookDetailsOpen: true})
}

closeBookDetails = () => {
    this.setState({ isBookDetailsOpen: false})
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>            
            <Search state={this.state} setTableData={this.setTableData} />
            <Table data={this.state.searchedBooks} openBookDetails={this.openBookDetails}/>
            <Modal data={this.state.searchedBooks} isBookDetailsOpen={this.state.isBookDetailsOpen} closeBookDetails={this.closeBookDetails} />
            {/* <Modal /> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Update:

Is the error thrown at that point or later because in the modal component I do see two references to data.title that would throw an error.

changes these lines as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="isbn">ISBN</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="isbn" aria-describedby="isbn" placeholder="Enter ISBN number" value={data[0].title}/>                               
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="copies">Number of Copies</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="copies" aria-describedby="copies" placeholder="Enter the number of copies" value={data[0].title}/>                  
                        </div>
```

In this case your input is trying to use a value of data.title which doesn't exist. Not sure if this doesn't work.

Comment: The data is from a server which is passed by mongoose. This data is then put into a object Array in searchedBooks Array in the state.

Comment: As for the data it gets called successfuly as an Object. When I console.log(typeof(data)) it is an object but why I can't traverse through the object is my problem.\

Comment: It still throws a TypeError. And thanks for the little tip with the arrow functions. Cleans up the code considerably.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around it.

Inside of the Modal I did

```
 let selectedBookDetails = []
 data.map(row => selectedBookDetails = row)
```

And then I accessed the data like this `selectedBookDetails.title`, `selectedBookDetails.author`, `selectedBookDetails.isbn`

Now the next challenge is getting it to edit. 
Thanks everyone for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use this:

```
console.log(data[0]?.title)
```

That will do the trick.