# Cannot access object property from an array in Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Even after looking at [how-to-iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696886/how-to-iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-handlebars), I could not make it work. I am using mongoose model, and want to simply iterate over objects and display both title and details:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const IdeaSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
details: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});

mongoose.model('ideas', IdeaSchema);
```

Here is my handlebars template:

```js
{{#each ideas}}
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
            <p>{{details}}</p>      
        </div>
{{/each}}
```

It displays 2 empty divs with no content inside:

```html
<div class="card card-body">
    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>      
</div>
<div class="card card-body">
    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>      
</div>
```

Here is the code that loads the collection

```
Idea.find({})
    .sort({ date: 'desc' })
    .then(ideas => {
        res.render('ideas/index', {
            ideas: ideas
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code snippet where you are populating the variable `ideas` and setting up handlebars. Please provide that, or if you aren't doing so, start with this:

You need to assign and likely export (if used in a different module) the model Mongoose is compiling for you like:

```
export const IdeaModel = mongoose.model('ideas', IdeaSchema);
```

and then use that to populate the variable `ideas` like:

```
const ideas = IdeaModel.find({}); // fetch all ideas or add query criteria
```

Then pass `ideas` into the handlebars `template` function like:

```
const html = template({ ideas });
```

Comment: here is the code you asked for:
`Idea.find({})
        .sort({ date: 'desc' })
        .then(ideas => {
            res.render('ideas/index', {
                ideas: ideas
            });
        });`

Comment: Check if the query is returning the data using console.log or a debugger. If it is, you'll need to consult the docs for whatever express middleware you're using and/or post the code that sets up the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I got fixing this issue by by installing a dev dependency for handlebars. See details on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59704492/3141885

Answer (score 0):

The code provided can solve

```
dbName.find({}).lean().then((ideas) => {
 res.render('ideas/index', { ideas: ideas });
});
```