# error using handlebars #each with node and express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "title" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See http://localhost:8080/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "description" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59721333/9370788) and have fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
// Idea Index Page
app.get('/ideas', (req, res) => {
  Test1.find({})
    .sort({date:'desc'})
    .lean()
    .then(ideas => {
      res.render('ideas/index', {
        ideas1: ideas
      });
    });
});
```

use `.lean()` and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good discussion on this issue with some suggestions on how to fix it, [link](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9396) . I upgraded my jest package with `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest` and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

download the package npm install @handlebars/allow-prototype-access
and import this to your app.js
`const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')`

and to app.engine()in your app.js
use this syntax:

```js
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars) },
));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars',);
```