# Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I got the issue with handlebars 4.7.3. I already checked the solution from this ask,
[Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "from" because it is not an "own property" of its parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690923/handlebars-access-has-been-denied-to-resolve-the-property-from-because-it-iss)
but it was no solution for my code so I hope someone can help me.

Controller.js

```
submitPosts: (req, res) => {
        // Check the attributs from create.handlebars for success or error message
        const newPost = new Post( {
            surname: req.body.surname,
            name: req.body.name,
            biography: req.body.biography,
            profilpicture: req.body.profilpicture,
            paintings: req.body.paintings,
        });
        // Safe new posts
        newPost.save().then(post => {
            console.log(post);
            flash('success-message', 'new post!')
            res.redirect('/admin/posts');
        });

    },
```

postModel.js

```
const
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema; // get props

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    // define props --> required for a post

    surname: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    biography: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    profilpicture: {
        type: Object,
    },
    paintings : {
        type: Object,
    }


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
```

index.handlebars

```
{{#each post}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ surname }}</td>
                <td>{{ name }}</td>
                <td><img style="width: 100px; height:100px;" src="{{ profilpicture }}"></td>
                <td>{{ biography }}</td>
                <td><img style="width: 100px; height:100px;" src="{{ paintings }}"></td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
```

Already tried every possibility from the other ask on stack overflow, other handlebars version, change router code, ... NOTHING WORKS :(

Comment: https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue that wrecked my nerves.
Tried additional packages etc but in the end a simple command solve this.
Its the Command ".lean()"
Found more here: [link to mongoose docs for lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

my code example:

```
// show message page Route
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
//read all Message entries from db
   Message.find() 
   //sort them descending by date property
   .sort({ date: "desc" })
   .lean()
   //take these and call the rendered page and pass them as object to the page
   .then(messages => {
     res.render("messages/show_messages", { messages: messages });
   });
});
```

Comment: @Dariun yes, use this inside your routes. My example is used inside a router file. therefore "router.get..." if you are not using a separate router file use the ".lean()" function inside your "app.get..." route.
Don't copy my route. insert ".lean()" in your route