# Angular 9 - Istanbul test coverage report being generated empty

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I'm getting an empty report, it's listing the files but it's not filling up the percentages...
Any idea on what can be causing it?

Error message:

***Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "statements" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.***

My package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.4",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.17",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
```

And here are the results in coverage/index.html file

[image: Coverage results]

Comment: first of all you have outdated dependencies in your package.json, try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to update your dependencies. Additionally, can you also post your karma.config.js?

Comment: Hey @YuriyKravets 
thanks for your comment. you were right, the problem was the karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter package that was out-of-date. After I execute the following npm update statement "npm i -D karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.1.1", it is working again.
Thank you

Answer (score 12):

The package "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter" was out-of-date.
After I execute the following npm update statement "***npm i -D karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.1.1***", it is working again.

Comment: this made my day!