# Access has been denied to resolve the property "size" because it is not an "own property" of its parent

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm using `express-handlebars` package (version: `4.0.4`) and rendering my code like this:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Snowy' }, {
      allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
      allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true
    });
})
```

But I am still getting same error. Any solution on Stackoverflow didn't work for me.

Comment: Have a look at this thread, it is similar to your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690923/handlebars-access-has-been-denied-to-resolve-the-property-from-because-it-is

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install older version of handlebar in your case. Paste this to your terminal and it should install the correct version of handlebars

```
npm uninstall express-handlebars && npm install express-handlebars@3.0.2
```

This version issue is probably related to your npm or node.js version on your machine.

Comment: The command below worked a little bit:
`let { allowInsecurePrototypeAccess } = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access');
app.engine("handlebars", handlebars({
  handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
}));`
I can access prototypes with this code (Example: `bot.users.cache.size`) bot cannot use commands like: `bot.users.cache.get("300573341591535617")`

I get this error: `Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'`

Comment: My code: `<div class="text-dark font-weight-bold h5 mb-0"><span>{{bot.users.cache.get("300573341591535617")}}</span></div>`

Comment: Hey, why did you removed you answers?

Comment: It was a wrong approach that is why i have removed my previous answer.You know when i check the error message, i actually noticed one thing 'size'. May be you will need to check if the `size` property exist on cache. I think there is the issue. Maybe you should use an if else statement to make sure the `size` property do exists. I think your problem is something pretty easy. It is just hard to guess without seeing the .hbs  view part of it.

Comment: No problem while using `.size`, I get error when I try to use proto method.