# Why doesn't {{user.username}} work in handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I need help using handlebars. I'm trying to insert an username into my `index.hbs` using `{{user.username}}`. The thing is that it shows me this:

> Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "username"
> because it is not an "own property" of its parent.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const passport = require('passport');

const app = express();
require('./database');
require('./config/passport');

//Configuracion
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'    
}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

//Middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'clavesecreta',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());

//Variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});

//Routes
app.use(require('./routes/index'));
app.use(require('./routes/videos'));
app.use(require('./routes/users'));

//Archivos estaticos
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Iniciar server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('El servidor esta escuchando en el puerto', app.get('port'))
});
```

Here is where I get the `user.username`. I also insert my `user.js` model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = async (password) => {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    return hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password){
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Comment: Presumably `req.user` is not a plain object, but without a [mre] it's hard to say where it came from.

Comment: I just updated all my index.js, sorry about that but im new at this. In my hbs I only insert {{user.username}}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "from" because it is not an "own property" of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690923/handlebars-access-has-been-denied-to-resolve-the-property-from-because-it-is)

Comment: Well, I looked into this before and I solved a lot of issues on my code. The problem is that I cant place a .lean() in res.locals.user = req.user || null; so I dont know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing `res.locals.user` in `app.js` middleware,  and moved it to the `userAuthenticated` function. And also add `.toJSON()` after `req.user` to serialized it.

Here's example code from my `userAuthenticated` function:

```
module.exports.userAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.locals.user = req.user.toJSON() || null;
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/');
},
```