# When a new image is added, the old image is automatically replasing in nodejs how to fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

I have created a file from which I can successfully upload the image, But the  name of the image that comes up ( undefiend.jpg ) in this project  use express file upload middleware

***admin.js**

```
var express = require("express");

const productHelpers = require("../helpers/product-helpers");

var router = express.Router();
var productHelper = require("../helpers/product-helpers");

/* GET users listing. */
  router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  productHelpers.getAllProducts().then((products) => {
    console.log(products);
    res.render("admin/view-products", { admin: true, products });
  });
});
router.get("/add-product", function (req, res) {
  res.render("admin/add-product");
});

router.post("/add-product", (req, res, next) => {
  productHelpers.addProduct(req.body, (id) => {
    let image = req.files.Image;

    console.log(id);
    image.mv("./public/product-images/" + id + ".jpg", (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.render("admin/add-product");
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

***product-helpers.js***
Here i do callback using id

```
   product-helpers.js` var db=require('../config/connection')
 var collection=require('../config/collections')
 module.exports={
     addProduct:(product,callback)=>{
     

    db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((data)=>{
          
      
      callback(data._id)
    })
  
  
     }
   
}
```

`

Comment: If the name of old and new images are same, old one will keep getting replaced.

Comment: You could try debugging by adding bunch of `console.log()` around the code. For example above `callback(data._id)` add `console.log("data", data);` This way you can track back the sequence at which each piece of code executed and the data it receives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use data.insertedId,

```js
  module.exports = {
    addProduct: (product, callback) => {
        db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((data) => {
            callback(data.insertedId)
        })
    }
}
```

in the mongodb documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/, it is showed that insertOne() returns

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true, 
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("56fc40f9d735c28df206d078")
}
```

> Insert a Document without Specifying an _id Field In the following
> example, the document passed to the insertOne() method does not
> contain the _id field:

```
try {
    db.products.insertOne({ item: "card", qty: 15 });
} catch (e) { print(e); };
```

> The operation returns the following document:

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true, 
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("56fc40f9d735c28df206d078")
}
```

But anyway, you can use the name property from `req.files.image`: for example:

```js
const image = req.files.image;
const imageName = image.name;
const imagePath = './public/product-images/' + imageName;
console.log(imagePath);
image.mv(imagePath, (error) => {
    //something here
})
```

If you want to use more properties, look at here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Comment: a similar question was answered here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690923/handlebars-access-has-been-denied-to-resolve-the-property-from-because-it-is)

Comment: Please fix the code fragments indentation

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso thank you for the information, I have tried to fix the code indentation.