# Unable to read JSON property. Property Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, crud

I have this document in my MongoDB

```
{
    _id: 603e59811a640a0d1097bc35,
    firstName: 'ABC',
    lastName: 'XYZ',
    address: 'Mars',
    age: 20,
    mobile: 9922334455,
    email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    password: 'pass',
    type: 'citizen',
    __v: 0
}
```

And below is the code I am using to fetch it:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        userName: req.body.userName,
        password: req.body.password,
    })

    User.findOne(
        {
            email: user.userName,
            password: user.password,
        },
        (err, data) => {
            console.log(data)
        }
    )
})
```

In console I am getting output as:

```
{
  _id: 603e59811a640a0d1097bc35,
  firstName: 'ABC',
  lastName: 'XYZ',
  address: 'Mars',
  age: 20,
  mobile: 9922334455,
  email: 'abc@gmail.com',
  password: 'pass',
  type: 'citizen',
  __v: 0
}
```

Now, when I am trying to access the data like `console.log(data.firstName)` its showing me as `undefined`. But if I do `console.log(data._id)` which is the first propertie's key, its giving the correct value which is `603e59811a640a0d1097bc35`

**Update**

I tried debugging and found this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YokJ.png)

The datatype of `result` is `model`. And if I use `${result._doc.firstName}` its giving me the first name. But is this the correct way of accessing the properties?

Comment: Do you store passwords as clear text in your database? You should **never** do this, store hash values instead!

Comment: I am learning node and MongoDB. Will do that later. Do you have the solution for the question I ashed?

Comment: Did you write `console.log(data.firstName)` at the exact same place as `console.log(data)`.

Comment: @t.niese yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use the `.then()` and `.catch()` methods on the collections, since they return a promise.

An example in your case would be:

```
await User.findOne({
        email: user.userName,
        password: user.password
    })
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            console.log(`Successfully found document: ${result}.`);
        } else {
            console.log("No document matches the provided query.");
        }
        return result;
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find document: ${err}`));
```

You can use the second parameter in `.findOne()` to specify any fields to include or exclude: `.findOne(data, {_id: 1, username: 1, password: 0)`

More information about this method:
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.findOne/

Comment: MongoDB provides a hybrid interface that supports callbacks and Promises. So using callbacks is one valid way of using it.

Comment: I tried using `${result.firstName}` in your code. Its still showing  `undefined`. The `result` has the data but for some reason its not able to access its properties.

Comment: How can you tell that it actually has the data?

Comment: @tysab, read the **Update** in the question

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solved. I used `.toObject()` on response data which converts `model` or `document` object into plane JS object

```
User.findOne({}, (err, data) => {
        const obj = data.toObject()
        console.log(objectt.firstName) // Logs 'ABC'
    })
```

Source of solution: [How do you turn a Mongoose document into a plain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object)