# Using Mongoose after cloning an found document as object additional fields appear on response

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use mongodb as database and mongoose as ODM, and express(nodejs) as backend.
So, I find item as:

```
const foundItem = await ItemModel.findOne({_id: 344363434643}).select(
      'name age'
);
```

after I clone the foundItem as:

```
const clonedFoundItem = {...foundItem}
```

But when I return it on frontend:

```
  res.send({
      data: clonedFoundItem
    });
```

I get some additional properties that not present in original object.

```
$__: {strictMode: true, selected: {…}, getters: {…}, _id: "344363434643", wasPopulated: false, …}
$init: true
$locals: {}
$op: null
isNew: false
_doc: {_id: "344363434643", name: 'Jim', age: '12'}
```

And they not presented on backend.

How I can get rid of its?

Comment: Why don't you return the founditem

Comment: Because I need to add some additional fields, some sort of computed fields, that not presented in original doc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object this may be interesting to you

Comment: Yes its works, i just added .lean() at const foundItem = await ItemModel.findOne({_id: 344363434643}).select(
      'name age'
).lean();