# I can't delete json object gotten from mongoose findone

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose

I am trying to remove some json object from a result of mongoose findone function

but is not working

My code

```
 export const transferGuest = async (req, res, next) => {
    
 var guest = await Booking.findOne({"roomNumber": req.body.roomNumber, booked: true}).sort({createdAt: -1})

    try{
        const newBooking = new Booking(guest)
        delete guest._id;
        return res.status(200).json(guest)

    }catch(error){
        next(error)
    }
}
```

but delete guest._id does not work.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findOne()` method returns a single document object so there's no need to call `sort()`. If I understand your question well, you want to remove the `_id` property from the result of the query. If that's the case, then you should try this:

```
export const transferGuest = async (req, res, next) => {

    try{
        var guest = await Booking.findOne({roomNumber: req.body.roomNumber, booked: req.body.booked}).select('-_id')
        const newBooking = new Booking(guest)
        return res.status(200).json(guest)
        //return res.send(guest);

    }catch(error){
        next(error)
    }
}
```

Note that you're not making use of `newBooking` variable, you should remove it if you're not going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply **delete**  function on mongoose object first you need to change in plain object after you can apply **delete** function on it.

For convert into plain object you can use **lean()** mongoose function in your mongoose query

For refrence [Change mongoose object into plain object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object)

```
const guest = await Booking.findOne({roomNumber: req.body.roomNumber, booked: req.body.booked}).lean();
```

**Try This:-**

```
export const transferGuest = async (req, res, next) => {
    
 var guest = await Booking.findOne({"roomNumber": req.body.roomNumber, booked: true}).lean();

    try{
        const newBooking = new Booking(guest)
        delete guest._id;
        return res.status(200).json(guest)

    }catch(error){
        next(error)
    }
}
```